# Executing cmd command "change port" from a variable

Tags: powershell

I'm having an issue with a pretty simple script and I think I'm just missing something fundamental. It checks to see if a certain device is plugged into a COM port, and if it it finds it, remaps it to COM1.

```
change port com1 /d
$ComNum = (change port) -match 'COM.+19h2kp0' -replace '^(COM\d+).+','$1'
$changeport = ("change port COM1=" + $ComNum)
$changeport
```

It seems to work perfectly, the output I get is

```
 change port COM1=COM4
```

The problem is that even though the output looks perfect, the command doesn't actually run. Is there a Powershell limitation to executing a cmd command from variable?

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are simply printing a variable (returning it, actually). You need to invoke it using [`Invoke-Expression`](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh849893.aspx), [`Invoke-Command`](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh849719.aspx) or simply use the `&` aka [Call operator](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee176949.aspx).

Comment: Thank you! Invoke-Expression seems to run the command, but for some reason when I run the change port command from powershell, it show the COM port as mapped, but the application doesn't think so. When I run the command from CMD.exe it remaps, and the application is happy. Is there a way to send the command to CMD from powershell?

Comment: try `& cmd /c $changeport`

Comment: No, I was actually just trying that. Powershell shows the port as mapped, but CMD does not. It's very strange that powershell and CMD show different outputs for change port.

Comment: Nevermind cmd /c works great from Powershell.exe . I was using ISE, and it won't work from there. Any idea why?